# How do you fix these visual studio errors when compiling?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When I tried to compile my project in c++ (from github and not my code) in visual studio, I get these errors and it fails to compile. [image: errors]

How do I fix these? I'm still super new to visual studio so best explain it in simple terms pls.
As in, what dependencies should I have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are some missing dependancies.

Comment: So which files should I add to the dependencies list? or is there somewhere where I can see those?

Comment: @SomeVMdude - The reference that contains the functions in question.  What versions of Visual Studio does the project repository indicate it supports?

Answer (score 0):

For one example, the
[GetProcessImageFileNameA function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea)
is found in the DLL `Psapi.dll` that is installed in the
`%windir%\System32` directory.

You should be sure to ensure that the folder containing the library
`Psapi.lib` is among your link libraries.